# Stopwatch code Issue

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a stopwatch app, for some reason when I press the start button in the app, instead of it going, 1,2,3,4,5 etc. It shows this '<'. I have gone over the code but I can find nothing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()

    var time = 0

    func result() {
        time + 1
        timeLabel.text = "\(timer)"
    }

    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()

        time = 0
        timeLabel.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func timeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a typo, your `timeLabel.text = "\(timer)"` should be `timeLabel.text = "\(time)"`.

Comment: And `time + 1` should be `time += 1`

Comment: Its not a typo, it would not work if I put time instead of timer.

Comment: Did you make the `time += 1` change as well?

Comment: yeah, still wont work.

Comment: Your code, with my 2 suggested modifications is working for me.  Make sure your `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction`s are wired up.

Comment: Working now, sorry, did something wrong, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: `timeLabel.text = "\(timer)"` should be `timeLabel.text = "\(time)"`.

Also, `time + 1` should be `time += 1`.  With those changes, the following code works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()

    var time = 0

    func result() {
        time += 1
        timeLabel.text = "\(time)"
    }

    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()

        time = 0
        timeLabel.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func timeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(result), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```